# Constructor with mutually exclusive members

Tags: c#

I have a class with mutually exclusive properties.

```
enum CellType : byte
{ Date, Teams, Value, Text }

class CellCheck
{
    public CellType CellType { get; set; }

    public float? MinValue { get; set; }
    public float? MaxValue { get; set; }

    public bool TextCaseSensitive { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
:
}
```

When CellType is Date or Teams MinValue, MaxValue, TextCaseSensitive and Text are irrelevant.
MinValue and MaxValue are only relevant when CellType is Value.
TextCaseSensitive and Text are only relevant when CellType is Text.

What is the best way to write the constructors ? Now I am using this :

```
    public CellCheck(float fMinValue, float fMaxValue) : this(CellType.Value, fMinValue, fMaxValue, false, null)
    {}

    public CellCheck(bool bTextCaseSensitive, string strText) : this(CellType.Text, null, null, bTextCaseSensitive, strText)
    {}

    public CellCheck(CellType Type, float? fMinValue, float ?fMaxValue, bool bTextCaseSensitive, string strText)
    {
        if (Type == CellType.Value)
        {
            if (!fMinValue.HasValue)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fMinValue argument in CellCheck constructor is null.");
            if (!fMaxValue.HasValue)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fMaxValue argument in CellCheck constructor is null.");
            if (fMinValue.Value > fMaxValue.Value)
                throw new ArgumentException("fMinValue argument in CellCheck constructor must be less or equal to fMaxValue argument.");

            bTextCaseSensitive = false;
            strText = null;
        }
        else
            if (Type == CellType.Text)
            {
                if (strText == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("strText argument in CellCheck constructor is null.");

                fMinValue = null;
                fMaxValue = null;
            }
            else
            {
                fMinValue = null;
                fMaxValue = null;

                bTextCaseSensitive = false;
                strText = null;
            }

        CellType = Type;

        MinValue = fMinValue;
        MaxValue = fMaxValue;

        TextCaseSensitive = bTextCaseSensitive;
        Text = strText;
    }
```

Is this considered a good programming practice ?

Comment: In reviewing this, I don't think I would create a public constructor that allowed the provision of min/max value for a CellType property for which there was no context. I'd defer that kind of error handling for property access and throw InvalidOperationExceptions when attempting to access those properties for the corresponding CellType values. Heck, in looking at it more, I'm not sure a generic might not be a better choice, eg CellCheck<T>.

Comment: Have you considered just makin Interfaces/Abstract classes to form a shallow but wide class heirarchy? The "type" value sounds like it should be part of the Derived Classes names: DateCell, ValueCell, etc.

Comment: If you really want one single class... just make the actual full constructor private. But this seems like it simply needs two classes, not one. You could make them derive from some common parent class though.

Comment: Seems to me like you need separate classes instead of a single class. What's the purpose if this class anyway? What common base do you have between cells of type Date, Team, Value and Text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When CellType is Date or Teams MinValue, MaxValue, TextCaseSensitive and Text are irrelevant. 
>   MinValue and MaxValue are only relevant when CellType is Value. 
>   TextCaseSensitive and Text are only relevant when CellType is Text.

Seems to me you need to have a different class for each cell type, all implementing a common interface:

```
interface ICellCheck
{
    // I'm guessing these classes should check the cells of something,
    // but this interface should hold Whatever the different 
    // CellCheck implementations have is common
    bool CheckCell();
}

class DateCellCheck : ICellCheck
{
    public bool CheckCell()
    {
        // implementation here
    }
}

class TeamCellCheck : ICellCheck
{
    public bool CheckCell()
    {
        // implementation here
    }
}

class ValueCellCheck : ICellCheck
{
    public float? MinValue { get; set; }
    public float? MaxValue { get; set; }    

    public bool CheckCell()
    {
        // implementation here
    }
}

class TextCellCheck : ICellCheck
{
    public bool TextCaseSensitive { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }    

    public bool CheckCell()
    {
        // implementation here
    }
}
```

Also, You might want to combine this implementation with the Factory method design pattern,
So the rest of your code doesn't need to know the implementation details of the interface:

```
enum CellType : byte
{ Date, Teams, Value, Text }

static class CellCheckFactory
{
    ICellCheck Create(CellType cellType)
    {
        switch(cellType)
        {
            case CellType.Date:
                return new DateCellCheck();
            case CellType.Teams:
                return new TeamCellCheck();
            case CellType.Value:
                return new ValueCellCheck();
            case CellType.Text:
                return new TextCellCheck();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, nice solution.

Comment: Glad to help :-)